# How do I import data from a delimited file into a Feature Class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a feature class created in a file geodatabase. How do I import data from a comma-delimited file into the feature class?

Update #1 - The destination is a feature class, not a table.

Comment: The solution I found feels clunky. I'll throw it out there and see if anyone can improve it.

As @Erica states, pipe-delimited files do not seem to be supported. Follow her steps to "Import Table (Single)". Then, right-click on the new XY table and select Create Feature Class > From XY Table. This step exports a shape file. The SHP file seems unnecessary. Next, right-click the geodatabase and select Import > Feature Class (Single). Point to the newly created SHP as the Input Features. The data, once in a delimited file, is now in the geodatabase as a feature class.

Comment: OK. I adjusted my answer to give you a shorter method; recurvata's approach also works quite well if you're adding to an existing feature class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS can't import pipe-delimited data (at least not that I am aware of). Do a quick search-and-replace on the source data to delimit with either commas (and save as a .csv file), or tabs if some fields have data with commas (and save as a .tab file).

Once you've got acceptably delimited data, you can [add an "XY Event Layer"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) through the File menu -> Add Data -> Add XY Data. This turns your data into an in-memory layer, and the layer can then be exported to your geodatabase (or a shapefile) for permanent storage. It brings along all the associated attribute data as well as the geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm getting up to speed on ESRI products and this exercise helped me to dig into various parts of ArcMAP I hadn't yet discovered. I suspect this entire process is something that could be automated with a python script (select a file & dump it into the gdb without any intermediate steps) but I'll save that for another day.

Comment: This can definitely be scripted -- I've done it a couple of times, and it only needs a couple lines of code. That's something that I wouldn't bother with unless you are going to be _very often_ importing CSV data, though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Load > Load Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Loading_data_in_the_Catalog_tree/003n0000003t000000/) in ArcCatalog. Right click the feature class to get the Load menu item. You get field mapping options as needed. Assumes you have a pre-existing feature class with appropriate fields.